# Convex Hexagon with one-sized angles property

Tags: geometry, puzzle, vectors

Let P be a Convex hexagon that all is angles are on the same size.
I want to show that every pair of opposing edges has the same difference (if one edge is in the size $x$ and it's opossing edge is of the size $y$, i want to show that $|x-y|$ is a constant).

Can someone give me a hint on how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. It's false. Draw some pictures.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Hexagon is convex, I edited my question

Comment: well i got it as homework so it's weird

Comment: could you help me create a counter example?

Comment: draw a regular hexagon. now move one of the edges out a little, so that it is parallel to the way it was. it is now a bit shorter, and the two edges that meet it are a bit longer. But three of the edges are exactly the way they were, and no angles changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the parallel sides as a,A and b,B, etc, it is possible to reduce this to a pentagon by reducing the sides by a, b, c.  The polygon remains closed, so one gets a hexagon whose opposite sides are a-a and A-a.

This is still a closed polygon with three non zero sides and equal angles, hence A-a= B-b =C-c.